# What is Meta key in Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap when used in linux?

Tags: intellij-idea

I changed Intellij keymap to Mac OS X 10.5+ on my LINUX box. For Cmd+O, now it says Meta+O? what is Meta or how to set it? Crtl, Fn, or Alt did not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a meta key by default in Linux.  You can obtain one by changing the keybindings  of the Super key to Meta.  Where you do this is specific to the desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

download this:
https://github.com/idf/dotfiles/blob/master/keylayout/OptDisabled.keylayout

To enable your new layout you must save it into your '~/Library/Keyboard Layouts', and then enable it from System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources.